# I am trying to get data from a solar data logger that exports csv reports to external cloud or api url

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I am trying to use aws lamda and api gateway to intake csv data directly from data logger periodically via HTTP post request into my lamda function which then sends it to a dynamodb table i am unable to proceed further as i keep running into same error again and again

```
{
    "message": "Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized token \'key\': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token \'null\', \'true\' or \'false\')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"key=datalogger'smacid&md5sum=b156f0d8bdb364f1a7131eac396510d4&data=ts,csv data from data logger"
}


here's my lamda function 


import boto3
import hashlib
import urllib.parse
import csv

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('#')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Extract the payload from the event
    payload = event['body']

    # Parse the payload into a dictionary
    payload_dict = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(payload))

    # Extract the individual fields from the payload
    key = payload_dict['key']
    data = payload_dict['data']
    md5sum = payload_dict['md5sum']

    # Parse the CSV data into a list of lists
    reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines())
    data_list = list(reader)

    # Verify MD5 sum
    data_encoded = data.encode('utf-8')
    try:
        calculated_md5sum = hashlib.md5(data_encoded).hexdigest()
    except:
        raise ValueError('An error occurred while calculating the MD5 sum')

    if calculated_md5sum != md5sum:
        raise ValueError('MD5 sum mismatch')

    # Store data in DynamoDB table
    for row in data_list[1:]:
        item = {
            'key': key,
            'timestamp': int(row[0]),
            # Assuming the rest of the values in the CSV correspond to the appropriate column headers
        }
        for i, value in enumerate(row[1:]):
            item[column_headers[i + 1]] = float(value)
        table.put_item(Item=item)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Added data successfully'
    }

additionally here's the data logger's log file i've modified it little bit 



Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5755
***sends csv data****
***gets back response****

3470 ms : [log_buf] 
SIZE_SENT=57553475 ms : [receive header] HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
3530 ms : [receive header] Date: Sat, 05 Aug 2023 00:12:50 GMT
3540 ms : [receive header] Content-Type: application/json
3550 ms : [receive header] Content-Length: 779
3560 ms : [receive header] Connection: keep-alive
3570 ms : [receive header] x-amzn-RequestId: a7501fc0-7aa4-4f6a-9862-7832ab61356
3595 ms : [receive header] x-amzn-ErrorType: BadRequestException
3615 ms : [receive header] x-amz-apigw-id: JKTTXH3vhcwFQSV=
3625 ms : [receive header] 
3625 ms : [receive] Waiting for body...
```

I tried changing lamda function again and again but it just doesn't accept anything other than json